# Wordpress query - order by meta_value - php: time(); - largest to smallest number

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to sort a column from the largest number to the smallest. The numbers are generated by the time () function in php (see image), currently my code has no influence on sorting. What am I doing wrong?

> p.s. 0 = nothing was found for this user_id in the database

[image: Database_column]

With the following line I place the value in the database

```php
// Update user meta
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'uls_last_seen', time() );
```

With this code line I retrieve the information from the database

```php
// Get user meta
$last_login = (int) get_user_meta( $user_id, 'uls_last_seen', true );
```

And this code to start sorting

```php
/**
 * Orderby user_last_seen (product)
 */
function uls_add_user_last_seen_column_orderby( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() )
        return;

    $orderby = $query->get('orderby');

    if( $orderby == 'user_last_seen' ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'uls_last_seen' );
        $query->set( 'orderby' , 'meta_value_num' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'uls_add_user_last_seen_column_orderby' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my question, I use `pre_get_users` instead of `pre_user_query`